# Is there a well-known port for logstash-forwarder?

Tags: centos, centos6, port, logstash

I'm setting up a few logstash-forwarder agents which will send logs to a central Logstash server, and need to choose a port for Logstash to listen on. After doing some searching, there doesn't seem to be a consensus about what this port number should be. The lumberjack protocol doesn't have a well-known port assignment as far as I can see.

The closest I was able to find as a convention was port 5000 (for example, [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-logs-on-centos-6)) but that strikes me as more of a tutorial, get-it-working-fast port.

Are there any established conventions for choosing this port number?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't one.

Answer (score -1):

default is 9200 as described in the logstash documentation: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/elasticsearch

Comment: That's the Elasticsearch port; I'm looking for the logstash-forwarder (lumberjack) port that the raw, unfiltered log messages enter through before Logstash processes them.